# Why does \n expand to n in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

When it comes to the [shell operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation), I can understand the step one, but the second step a little puzzles me. Here is my understanding:

First, shell splits input into words and operators, then performs according to quoting rules. Here is some of my questions. When I execute:

```
$ \n
bash: n: command not found
```

Why is it the `n: command not found`? not `\n: command not found`?

```
$ $'\n'
bash: $'\n': command not found
```

Why doesn't it perform ANSI-C Quoting?

By the way, when the input is a script file, how does it split into words and operators? Line by line or as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash quotes the following character (see QUOTING in `man bash`). `\n` is therefore interpreted as `n` (and being the first word of a command, this would prevent alias expansion, see ALIASES in `man bash`).

`$'\n'` **is** interpreted as ANSI-C quoted. Bash just uses the same quoting to show the problematic character. You can get the same error from

```
'
'
```

which is equivalent to it.

The process of word splitting is described at the beginning of `man bash`. If you're in doubt, ask a more concrete question, or check the [source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Comment: @choraba, is the meaning of escape here something different than that in C/C++ string, is `\<char>` just `<char>` when it comes to bash escaping? where <char> could be any single character. But why this would preven alias expansion? `man bash` just says `Aliases  allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.` Isn't command `\n` just the case? Sorry for the delay. :)

Comment: Yes, outside of quotes, `\n` and `n` are the same. Try it with `l\s`. Backslash prevents alias expansion by design. `\n` is the same as `n`, both return `command not found`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I fully understand it now. And the wiki page about [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) helps me understand better.